# How can I prevent WordPress from altering or messing with the custom Javascript?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin that has several features and one of those is add custom Javascript code to the Wordpress pages/posts. My problem is on the settings page of this plugin that I'm currently making.

I have a field/text area where the user could put the custom Javascript code that they want. However, WordPress seems to be messing with the Javascript code. It puts a backslash somewhere in the code so that it won't work. So for example you want this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.write('<h1>Hello World!</h1><p>Have a nice day!</p>');
</script>
```

WordPress changes it to:

```
<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
document.write(\'<h1>Hello World!</h1><p>Have a nice day!</p>\');
</script>
```

I'm getting really frustrated with this. Is there a function I could use to retain the code that I've put or a function that could tell WordPress not to alter/mess up with the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `html_entity_decode(stripslashes($yourcontent))` it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Ok, I will try out this solution and I'll let you know when it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP `'stripslashes'` before you output it back into the text field.

Usage: `string stripslashes ( string $str )`